# Copying only sliced data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have these set of codes now. How to i code it such that it will paste the copied value below the last row with a value in the PivotTable sheet. Like after it has run through the first slice and pasted the values in column A of the PivotTable sheet. It goes through the second slice, copy and paste the values continuing from the last cell with value from slicer#1. And also instead of `For CurrentSlice = 1 To 20` is there a way i can amke it run through all the slicer option without a range?

```
Sub IterateSlices()
  Dim CurrentSlice As Integer
  ActiveSheet.Name = "BSC"
  Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
  For CurrentSlice = 1 To 20
   SelectOnly ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Engine_S_N."), 
   CurrentSlice


  Sheets("BSC").Select
  Columns(2).EntireColumn.Select
  Selection.copy
  Sheets("PivotTable").Select
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Next
End Sub

Sub SelectOnly(Slicer As SlicerCache, SliceNo As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
' Force at least one to be selected before start
Slicer.SlicerItems(Slicer.SlicerItems.Count).Selected = True

For i = 1 To Slicer.SlicerItems.Count
    Debug.Print (SliceNo = i)
    Slicer.SlicerItems(i).Selected = (SliceNo = i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `Activecell` , my guess is that's the Problem. You need to use actual references using `Range("A:A")` types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine now but how do i code it such that it would paste the value below the last row with data?